# My shell script to start my rails application does not seem to run the code `cd` is expected to run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, initialization

I wrote a script to start my rails application. It includes many services so I want to use that script whenever I restart my computer.

The script is pretty simple, it uses `cd <some-folder>` and then starts the service defined there. For example, I start druid this way:

```
cd ~/apache-druid-0.16.0-incubating
./bin/start-micro-quickstart 1>~/log/druid.log 2>&1 &
sleep 10
```

The sleep is somewhat arbitrary but I know it's sufficient.

When I want to start my rails service, though, it fails.

```
cd ~/my-app
rails s &
```

The logs show this error:

```
/home/alexis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:495:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.3 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
        from /home/alexis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:470:in `validate_runtime!'
        from /home/alexis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
        from /home/alexis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/alexis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/alexis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

This clearly tells me that the `cd ~/my-app` did not work as expected. That is, when I do it in my bash shell, I get a message like so:

```
alexis@my-vps:~ $ cd my-app/
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/alexis/my-app/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

alexis@my-vps:~/my-app $ _
```

and I know that it tweaks the environment so my rails application starts as expected (with the correct version of Ruby and other tools).

How do I replicate the behavior of the `cd` command in my shell script?

Comment: I don't know how to replicate the behavior of the `cd` command. However, what I do in my scripts (when starting up my servers after a reboot - I tend to run at least four or five at a time including background job servers) is explicitly do a `rvm use ruby-2.5.3@my-app` (or whatever ruby version). That seems to work for me. It may or may not be relevant for you.

Comment: @jvillian Ah. That `rvm use ...` did not work. I got a message telling me that's because my shell is not a login shell. I tweaked my script first line and now it works! See my answer for details. Thank you for the hint, though!

Answer (score 1):

When I tried @jvillian's solution (see comment):

```
# force specific version of rvm
rvm use ruby-2.5.3@my-app
```

I got the following error:

> RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
>
> You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
>   Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
>   Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.

Looking at the info at the specified link, I could see that the idea was to have a login shell so the `cd` would work. So I changed my script first line from:

```
#/bin/sh -e
```

To using:

```
#/bin/bash -el
```

and now I can see that the `cd` works as expected.

This is most certainly because now the script loads the `.bashrc` and other such files which add the proper `cd` support, as you get by default in your console.

Now all my services start as expected.